# What is the role of "dr-" at the beginning of certain adverbs?

Tags: grammar, adverb

I'm referring to word groups like oben and droben, or außen and draußen.

Does the *"dr-"* represent something in its own right, perhaps a contraction of *"dr-"*?

Apparently, they lend some subtle changes or shades of meaning to the above-mentioned adverbs. How does that come about?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The adverb *droben* is a short form of "dort oben". It's contracted for "daroben" which is not used anymore. The word *"droben"* itself isn't very commonly used in everyday language though.

*draußen* is a popular adverb, meaning *outside* or *outdoors*. I'm not sure, but it could also have its origin from the word *"dort"* (in combination with *außen*) or as [Takkat wrote](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/what-is-the-role-of-dr-in-front-of-certain-adverbs/2496#2496): a contraction of *daraußen* (not a word in modern German).

There are other examples of adverbs starting in *dr-:*

- drunter (short for *darunter*)
- drin (darin)
- drüber (darüber)

Answer (score 11):

Both examples come from a contraction of two words into one evolving from [Middle High German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_High_German):

> draußen - mhd. *dār ūʒen*<sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drauszen)</sup>

or, in your other example from

> droben - *dort oben*<sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/droben)</sup>

Examples where both variants coexist are

> dran - daran, drüber - darüber, drum - darum, drauf - darauf [...]