# Difference between local adverbs -aus/-ein and außen/innen

Tags: adverb

I have several problems trying to figure out when to use the following adverbs

- heraus/hinaus (I ended using raus...)
- herein/hinein (same but rein ...)
- Draußen/außen
- Drinnen/innen

I checked these links, but were not so clear to me.

[heraus/hinaus/herein/hinein](http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?3,20618)

[Draußen/außen/Innen/drinnen](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/adjektiv/adverb/unterschied-aussen-draussen-innen-drinnen/)

Comment: I find those linked explanations quite clear, what do you not understand about them? In any case, your question is too broad (mixes two different issues), and both parts are duplicates: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/what-is-the-role-of-dr-at-the-beginning-of-certain-adverbs, http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7794/how-to-use-the-hin-and-her-prefixes Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the prefix in this case the adverbs Her and Hin.

The words depend on position and direction.

If you want someone to come to you say "Komm hier her!" = Come here.

If you want someone to go some where else you say "Geh da hin!" = Go there.

So if you want to say e.g.: Enter my room! 
It depends on whether you are in the room or not.

If you are inside the room you say:"Komm in mein Zimmer herein!"
if you are outside the room you say:"Geh in mein Zimmer hinein!"

Same goes for aus:

If you are inside the room you say:"Geh aus meinem Zimmer hinaus!" (away from me)
if you are outside the room you say:"Komm aus meinem Zimmer heraus!" (towards me)

Außen und Innen and Draußen und drinnen is dependend on the reference area.

Something has an Außen and Innen.
"Deine Organe sind Innen und deine Haut ist außen." = Your organs are on the inside and your skin is on the outside.

But Somthing is Draußen or Drinnen
"Du bist draußen andere sind drinnen." = You are inside others are outside.

Hope this clarify this...